# Using await / async with mocha, chai

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, chai

I'm quite new to node and express.
And have been trying to write test code using mocha, chai and chai-http.
Here's the part of source code.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  User = require('../../models/user');

const mongoUrl = 'mongodb://xxxxxxxxxxx';

describe('/test', function() {
  before('connect', function() {
    return mongoose.createConnection(mongoUrl);
  });

  beforeEach(async function(done) {
    try {
      await User.remove({}); // <-- This doesn't work
      chai.request('http://localhost:3000')
        .post('/api/test')
        .send(something)
        .end((err, res) => {
          if (err) return done(err);
          done();
        });
    } catch (error) {
      done(error);
    }
  });
});
```

And I get the following error with "npm test"(nyc mocha --timeout 10000 test/**/*.js).

```
Error: Timeout of 10000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

I confirmed the database connection works properly from log.
And seems I get the timeout error with await User.remove({}).
I've also tried different methods such as a User.save()
But, I got the same error.
Do I need to do something special with database model and connection?

Comment: There's no evidence that 'This doesn't work'. Failed test only means that done wasn't called.

Comment: Just a guess, but it may be hanging if your DB connection isn't closed.  Is it hanging in the specific `before` or because the entire test suite doesn't close?  Try adding an `after` block that closes the connection by keeping the `Connection` returned by `createConnection` and calling `.close()` on it.  Does that make a difference?

Comment: I confirmed inserting console.log() everywhere and didn't proceed transaction from that line any more. There is no exact evidence.

Comment: I already have the following. after(function() {  mongoose.connection.close(); }

Comment: @Gianfrance So you put `console.log()` before `chai.request()` and it's not called, correct? The question is incorrect then. It's not specific to async/await or Mocha. It's that `User.remove({})` takes longer than 10s. There's also no evidence that the error refers to `beforeEach`; actual tests aren't shown.

Comment: I've resolved the problem myself that as I expected I had to get database model from connection. var db = mongoose.createConnect(url); NewModel = db.model('Model', Model.ModelSchema); It's because I'm using docker and port no of host and docker is different?

Answer (score 7):

This is all pretty simple.

To avoid the error you must not use both `done` and `async/await` in Mocha at the same time. Either use `async/await` and remove both `done` as function parameter and `done()` call. Or use `done`. Then remove both `async/await`. See the example tests below for each case.

Use `try/catch` with `async/await` as you would normally use it with synchronous code.

Following are the most basic Mocha tests with both `async/await` and `done` approaches testing the same basic HTTP server endpoint.

This is `async/await` approach.

```js
it('with async/await', async function() {
    const res = await chai.request(server)
        .get('/')
        .send();
    assert.equal(res.status, 200);
});
```

This is `done` approach.

```js
it('with done & callbacks', (done) => {
    chai.request(server)
        .get('/')
        .end((err, res) => {
            assert.equal(res.status, 200);
            done();
        });
});
```

See the [full test file snippet](https://gist.github.com/WhereJuly/176ec66437b73a7378d1395c044e5ffe).

For working example additionally spin [basic Express server](https://gist.github.com/WhereJuly/7b275ec75380505aa9db9a384f0e4ab3) as the tests counterpart in `src/app.js`.

See [Chai HTTP](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-http/) plugin docs for more info on what you can do with request testing.

This is it.

Answer (score 5):

[I had the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52485669/mocha-not-continuing-after-before-that-includes-a-promise-just-hangs) and have not found a way to get any promises that involve `mongoose` working with Mocha/Chai.

What may help you is doing what I did and putting your mongoose code in a script so you can run it with `node <scriptfile>.js`. You can use that to confirm it's working properly by itself. In my test, the mongoose operation finished in less than a second. You can also call that file from another (non-test related) to confirm it executes properly and returns a promise. You can see from my [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52485669/mocha-not-continuing-after-before-that-includes-a-promise-just-hangs) how to make sure you close db properly. Partial example:

```
  ...
  db.close();

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    db.on('disconnected', () => {
      console.log('***************************************Mongoose CONNECTION TERMINATED');
      resolve('user ready');
    });
  });
  ...
```

You may also find some clues by looking at the following issues [here](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/3050) and [here](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/3044).

The work around that I did after wasting too much time trying to figure out this crazy behavior was to perform my mongoose needs in a route. I wrap each request that needs to use it in the `end` block of the extra `chai.request...` or use async. Example:

```
describe('something', () => {
  it('should do something and change it back', async () => {
    try {
      // change user password
      let re1 = await chai.request(app)
        .post('/users/edit')
        .set('authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
        .send({
          username: 'user@domain.com',
          password: 'password6',
        });
      expect(re1.statusCode).to.equal(200);

      // change password back since before hook not working
      let re2 = await chai.request(app)
        .post('/users/edit')
        .set('authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
        .send({
          username: 'user@domain.com',
          password: 'password6',
          passwordNew: 'password',
          passwordConfirm: 'password',
        });
      expect(re2.statusCode).to.equal(200);
    } catch (error) {
      // error stuff here
    }
  });
```

Note that using the `try/catch` syntax above will cause test that should normally fail to show passing and the results will be caught in the catch block. If you want to avoid that, just remove the `try/catch`.

Comment: Thanks!  This worked for me.  Assign response value to await result of chai, and get rid of the .end()  or it displays "double callback" in the output.

Answer (score 0):

How did you implement `./models/user`? `await` only works if `User.remove()` returns a promise, not if it expects a callback. I would add debug information to your `User.remove()` function to see where it gets stuck.