# Mocha not continuing after "before" that includes a promise, just hangs

Tags: mongoose, mocha.js

My `mocha` test hang when i use a promise inside a `before` function. I have the following `before` that calls an external function that returns a promise.

```
describe('User Tests', () => {
  let token = '';
  before(() => {
    const afunc = require('../../../controllers/somefunction');
    return afunc().then((val) => {
      console.log('what is val?', val);
    });
  });

  //... other test are below it like...

  describe('get own profile', () => {
    it('should return profile of logged-in user', (done) => {
      chai.request(app)
        .get('/access/users/profile')
        .set('authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
        .end((err, res) => {
          expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200);
          done();
        });
    });
  });

});
```

`afunc` from `../../../controllers/somefunction` works fine on its own (returns after db disconnects) looks like the following:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = require('../../models/access/user');
// Use native promises
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const db = mongoose.connect(`mongodb://localhost/${availableDBs[dbTarget] || availableDBs.test}`, {
  keepAlive: true,
  reconnectTries: 3,
  useMongoClient: true,
});
// const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

const dbconnect = () => new Promise((resolve) => {
  db.once('open', () => {
    console.log('DB Open and Listening');
    resolve('DB Open and Listening');
  });
});

const newSuperUser = async () => {
  await dbconnect();
  const user = await User.findOne({ username: data.username.toLowerCase() });
  if (user === null) {
    console.log('Create new user');
    const newUser = await new User(data).save();
    console.log('newUser', newUser);
    if (newUser === null) {
      return console.log('Username already exists.');
    }
    console.log('Successfully created new user.');
  } else {
    console.log('Deleting original user');
    const deleted = await User.findOneAndRemove({ username: data.username });
    console.log('Deleted user', deleted);
    console.log('Create new user after deleting original');
    const newUser = await new User(data).save();
    console.log('newUser', newUser);
    if (newUser === null) {
      return console.log('Username already exists.');
    }
    console.log('Successfully created new user.');
  }

  db.close();

  await new Promise((resolve) => {
    db.on('disconnected', () => {
      console.log('***************************************Mongoose CONNECTION TERMINATED');
      resolve('user ready');
    });
  });
  return true;
};

if (process.argv.some(array => ['test', 'pro', 'dev'].includes(array))) {
  newSuperUser();
}

module.exports = newSuperUser;
```

The console.log shows it returns a value. I've also tried the following alternate way and get the same result:

```
describe('User Tests', () => {
  let token = '';
  before((done) => {
    const afunc = require('../../../controllers/somefunction');
    afunc().then((val) => {
      console.log('what is val?', val);
      done();
    });
  });

  //... other test are below it like...

  describe('get own profile', () => {
    it('should return profile of logged-in user', (done) => {
      chai.request(app)
        .get('/access/users/profile')
        .set('authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
        .end((err, res) => {
          expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200);
          done();
        });
    });
  });

});
```

I even tried to wrap the `before` inside another `describe` like this (but at that point it didn't even run the `before` anymore):

```
describe('User Tests', () => {
  let token = '';
    describe('User Tests', () => {
    before((done) => {
      const afunc = require('../../../controllers/somefunction');
      afunc().then((val) => {
        console.log('what is val?', val);
        done();
      });
    });
  });

  //... other test are below it like...

  describe('get own profile', () => {
    it('should return profile of logged-in user', (done) => {
      chai.request(app)
        .get('/access/users/profile')
        .set('authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
        .end((err, res) => {
          expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200);
          done();
        });
    });
  });

});
```

I've tried returning the promise and the alternate method of calling `done()`. Why would mocha hang here?

`Mocha 5.2.0`

Comment: Quick question, your user test is not very explicit, what exactly are you trying to test with your user model? And why two separate `describe()` blocks? Are they not both testing something with the `User` model? Are you working with MongoDB? Can you post your model file of `User`?

Comment: Hey @Daniel, User model is not relevant here. Comment is too short for me to explain why. I can (and have) done the same thing in `Jest` using the same "somefunction" example from above and it works fine but Jest requires full `request` setup for implementation test and Mocah/Chai allow the syntax above. The describe blocks are for grouping. In this example, outermost defines "User Test".

Comment: There are others like "Inventory Test" etc. Next Level 2 inside "User Test" might look like describe "get profile", describe "change profile". The `before` function needs to see "somefunction" resolve. It resolves properly when run in terminal or by any other part of the app. There is only a issue when it's inside Chai. You can test this with ANY mongoose transaction and the same problem. In other implementations this is usually because of improperly closing DB connection. I posted "somefunction" so knowledgeable people could see that or improper promise is not problem.